# How to set up environment variables for production in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, netlify

When i deployed mysite on **netlify**, it was successfully deployed. But it does not work. and when I inspected i came to know that my app is still hitting the **localhost** . My question is how should I declare environment variables? I am new to this..

Axios file-

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../store/index'

export default ()=>{
    return axios.create({
    baseURL:process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL ||
    process.env.API_BASE_URL ||`http://localhost:8082/`,
    headers:{
        authorization:`${store.state.token}`
    }
    })
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          // modify the options...
          return options
        })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables are only accessible server side. In order for the client side to have the values you need to declare it in the global scope.

Webpack has a plugin specifically for this called `DefinePlguin`:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Something like:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL),
});
```

Then, in the client you can access `BASE_URL`

Comment: Hi sir.. I have deployed my front-end on **netlify** and backend on **heroku** and I passed the backend URL to the client which is `https://vue-blogger.herokuapp.com/` so is it correct ? My app still requests to localhost? can you please help me with this?

Comment: thanks sir.. your suggestion helped me to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.env.development` and `.env.production` files for development and production variables respectively.

You can check [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use Netlify environmental variables also locally, by using Netlify Dev: https://www.netlify.com/products/dev/
I've done that in one of my projects recently: https://github.com/sunyamare/ubiqum-tgif
Note: It seems you can only use the variables in Netlify (lambda) functions.